# Does updating app in iTunes loses the previous files and data stored in app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, app-store

I have an iPad application which saves the files in it and i have release it in appstore. Now if the update the app does my previous files in that app gets deleted.

Comment: Search here on SO... there are dozens of this exact same question with great answers that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the document folder is not modifyed, so depends of what data you are interested in... I mean, the resource bundle is overwritten, so you can't ADD resources incrementally, but if yousaved some data in Document you'll find them also after update.